# How to create multiple identical independent GitHub pull requests for a given patch?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am creating a programming class dedicated to the practices of software code review. During the class, students are expected to perform code reviews over pre-made change requests (by commenting pull requests in a GitHub project). After each review is prepared, we will compare them and discuss different aspects of students' thinking, their motivation, etc. etc.

The size of the audience is expected to be large (dozens to hundreds of participants). What I want to do is to split them into smaller groups (2-3 in each) and to give each group their own but otherwise identical pull request to comment on. This way, results of individual discussion groups would be easier to compare. At the same time, working on independent pull requests will isolate these groups from interference of what others are concurrently doing.

The question is how to organize it technically. I know that I can push the same local branch multiple times to several differently named remote branches, then navigate to them  in my browser and create a pull request from each of them. Amount of manual work for this method scales linearly with the number of desired pull requests?

**Using which scripting/programming tools would allow me to automate this process?**

In other words, given a local branch, I want to create a set of pull requests in the same GitHub project, and have a (sequential) range of PR numbers for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create pull requests on GitHub from their API: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-pull-request

Once the PR exists, you should be able to request reviews from specific people: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/review-requests?apiVersion=2022-11-28#request-reviewers-for-a-pull-request

Note that you won't be able to get a specific PR number from the API; GitHub manages those.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I tried using this Github API with help of `curl` and was able to create a new pull request. A couple of observations: 1. The response text from the POST request is JSON that actually contains the URL to the new pull request, so, if needed, I can obtain it; 2) The API does not allow to create more than one pull request from a single remote branch, but given than I can push the same local SHA several times into multiple remote branches, I can then create multiple pull requests out of them. I think I can work with that.